# PHP check if after midnight

Tags: php, cron, unix-timestamp

How do I check after midnight? For example, I have this code

```
// Run cron job if passed 24 hours (86400 seconds), 
// but only if it's after midnight

if ( (time() - $LastUpdate) >= 86400 && PAST_MIDNIGHT ) {
      do something ...
}
```

How do I  fill in PAST_MIDNIGHT? My intention is to run a cron job once per day, but only after midnight. Thank you.

Comment: It's *always* after midnight

Comment: ...somewhere am sure.

Comment: You need to define midnight as a time *and date*. @JohnConde is right, it's always 'after midnight' but you can turn that statement sane with "is it past midnight on December 18, 2013?". How about "is it past midnight on the date of `$LastUpdate`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of hackish, but this with check if the current server time hour (in 24 hour format) is less than 7. So, anywhere from midnight (0) to 7:00am (7) will pass. Other times won't.

```
if ( (time() - $LastUpdate) >= 86400 && (date('G') < 7)) {
  do something ...
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for a list of parameters you can throw at date().

Answer (score 2):

Given that midnight is the first second of the day, it's never not 'past midnight'.

Since you're using cron, have it scheduled to run at the time you need it to run.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase (I am confused :) ) My intention is not to run during the day, but only after midnight whenever the server resource is available, doesn't matter the exact time. Maybe I have to say past first second?

Comment: Are you saying that you only want the script to run between two times? For example 00:00:00 and 08:00:00?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a unix system, you can use the **cron** service:

Run this in your console:

```
crontab -e
```

And then add the following at the last line:

```
@daily /full/path/to/php /full/path/to/your/script.php
```

This will execute every day at midnight